# How do I customise my dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery dropdown but my `div` is strangely aligned. At the moment the parent `div` of the dropdown is in the top right corner of the page and the red dropdown is aligned toward the end of the screen. How can I align the dropdown so that its right side is aligned with the right border of the arrow?

Here is the current behavior:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
#jsddm {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#jsddm li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    font:12px Tahoma,Arial;
}
#jsddm li a {
    display:block;
    padding:13px 12px;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#jsddm li a:hover {
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:13px 12px;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#jsddm li ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    border-top:1px solid white;
}
#jsddm li ul li {
    float:none;
    display:inline;
}
#jsddm li ul li a {
    width:auto;
    background:#9F1B1B;
}
#jsddm li ul li a:hover {
    background: #7F1616;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle example? We can help you better if we know the actual HTML :-)

Comment: Got to see HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your existing CSS selectors::

```
#jsddm li {
    position:relative;
}

#jsddm li ul { 
    right:0;
}
```

Live Sample *(used simplified markup since your HTML is not included by the time of this writing)*:

http://jsfiddle.net/u6QtX/2/